# Php Regular Expression Debugging

Tags: php, regex, debugging

i am using the following regular expression

`/^(?P<prefix>admin{1})?[\/]?(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)[\/]?(?P<method>[a-z-]+)[\/]?(?P<parameters>[a-z0-9-\/]+(?=\/page))?[\/]?page\/(?P<page>[0-9]+)?$/i`

i want it to find a match using the following:

`controller/method/parameters/another/something`

`controller = controller, method = method, parameters = parameters/another/something`

but if the supplied argument is

`controller/method/parameter/another/something/page/1`

it should return:

`controller = controller, method = method, parameters = parameter/another/something, page = 1`

i am only getting a match if i supply the `page/1` argument. any help debugging what is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Have you tried this web service to debugging regex?(https://regex101.com)

Comment: yes, i'm still using it to debug the regex since morning. https://regex101.com/r/sI7qP2/3

Answer (score 0):

A lookahead can't be optional, and also your parameter regex is too greedy. You could solve this problem by switching the positions of `page` and `parameters` if `page` is not a mandatory parameter!

(and additionally you don't need the square brackets around the escaped slashes!)